# Setup webpack sass-loader to separate styles

Tags: css, sass, webpack, loader

In my app, I have such folder structure for styles

- styles

  1. head
  2. main

Head folder contains styles which supposed to be in `<style>` tag to fast render first screen.

The main folder contains styles which supposed to be compiled into `style.css`.

How can I setup web pack sass-loader to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your loaders in your webpack config add:

```
{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style!css?modules=true&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!sass'

}
```

Then for head and main you can name them with the `scss` extension and 
import them like this (in your JS file)

```
import head from './head.scss'
import '!style!css?sass!<path-to-your-main>main.scss'
```

Then you can use it in your JSX like this:

```
<p className={head.myHeaderStyle}>Some text</p>
```